# Kendall's tau coefficent of Bivariate Normal

Tags: probability, statistics, covariance, correlation

Let the joint distribution of (, ) be bivariate normal with mean vector
$\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
0\end{pmatrix}$ and variance-covariance matrix
$\begin{pmatrix}
1 &  \\
 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$, where $− <  < $. Let
$_{}(, ) = ( ≤ ,  ≤ )$. Then what will be Kendall’s  coefficient between 
and  equal to?

Since I am new to statistics I have no idea where to start?

Comment: Kendall's $\tau$ is a measure of correlation that is non-parametric. It can be applied to any observed data $(X_1, Y_1), \ldots, (X_n, Y_n).$

Comment: Check https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3058888/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1687795/321264

Answer (score 1):

Originally, [Kendall's tau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_correlation#Kendall%27s_%CF%84_as_a_particular_case), also called rank correlation, is a statistical measure that can be applied to a discrete set of observed data.

In the more recent literature about dependency modelling with Copulas which became popular in mathematical finance the following definition of Kendall's tau is given.

Let $\Phi_\rho(x,y),\Phi(x),\Phi(y)$ be the bivariate and the univariate CDFs of the standard normal distribution. Then the Gaussian Copula is defined as
$$
C_\rho(x,y)=\Phi_\rho(\Phi^{-1}(x),\Phi^{-1}(y))
$$
Kendall's tau is then defined as
\begin{align}
\rho_\tau&=\mathbb E\Big[{\rm sign}[(X-\tilde{X})(Y-\tilde{Y})]\Big]\\
&=\mathbb P\Big[(X-\tilde{X})(Y-\tilde{Y})>0\Big]-P\Big[(X-\tilde{X})(Y-\tilde{Y})<0\Big]\,.
\end{align}
where $(X,Y)$ is bivariate standard normal, and $(\tilde{X},\tilde{Y})$ has the same distribution but is independent of $(X,Y).$
It can be shown (see [1] and [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3058888/kendalls-tau-of-bivariate-normal)) that
$$
\rho_\tau=4\int_0^1\int_0^1C_\rho(x,y)\,dC_\rho(x,y)-1=\frac{2}{\pi}\arcsin\rho\,.
$$

[1] M. Haugh, An Introduction to Copulas. *IEOR E4602: Quantitative Risk Management Spring 2016*. http://www.columbia.edu/